# levelc omplete with global variable

Tags: construct-2

I have an issue with finishing a level using global variable when I make a global variable for enemy count is = 0  then add 1 to level variable, but when I start the game and destroy all enemies the global variable keep adding 1 to levels Continuously and all levels are unlocking along with this variable.
Now I want it should add only one level

Answer (score 0):

2 Issues here:

1. Use add `trigger once while true` as a condition to the event that checks if count = 0.  Without this, every tick that condition is true (before another enemy spawns) `level` will be incremented.
2. You don't wan't to start checking until the first enemy spawns.  One possible solution is to add a global variable called `isGameStarted` initialized to 0.  Then using an `onCreated` event for your enemies, set `isGameStarted` to 1.  Finally, add another condition to your level increment event that checks to make sure `isGameStarted = 1.` Any time you are going to wipe all the enemies, make sure to set `isGameStarted = 0` first to avoid triggering a level change.